# Use static framework inside a dynamic swift framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I am creating custom dynamic framework in pure swift lang which is using a pre-compiled iOS Realm framework ([downloaded from their website](https://static.realm.io/downloads/cocoa/realm-cocoa-0.91.5.zip)). I have tried various options to use this framework in an external project but it fails saying Realm was not found.

Here are some of the things I have tried already

- Used Realm binary and headers from the framework, added them to the
  project and import using a plain `import Realm` statement
- Use the framework in the project ad directed by the instructions on
  the above link. `#import <Realm/Realm.h>` in the umbrella header of
  the framework

In both cases the framework compiled without any errors. But when I try to compile another project which uses my framework, I get different errors

- Swift compiler error- Module 'Realm' not found (in the MyFramework-Swift.h file)
- `<Realm/Realm.h>` file not found (inside the umbrella header)

My questions

- is it possible to use a framework inside a dynamic framework?
- if it is, do I need to give specific compile settings in order for a wrapper project to find Realm framework in MyFramework?